# Import Android project from Github into Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, gradle

I have single Github repository containing several directories where each directory is "root" for another Android project. I need to import to AS only one of the projects. When I creating new project in AS from Github I can insert only the repository URL. So I get in the project tree in AS one module which is the Github repository with several folders each one of them assigned with different Android project. The problem is those folders are not Modules and therefore I cannot threat them as Android project.

How can I change this?

Note - I cannot make any changes in the Github structure.

Comment: Can't you just `git clone` from the terminal/command-prompt and then from AndroidStudio just `open an existing AndroidStudio project`?

Comment: Just open up the sub-directory as a project

Comment: here is example from GraphView: http://www.android-graphview.org/download--getting-started.html (see option 1 & 3)

Comment: I cant clone sub folder in the repo only the repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio and Eclipse have different workspace.

In the Eclipse workspace you can define more projects.

In the Android Studio workspace you can define 1 project with more modules.
Each project have the `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` files, and each module has a own `build.gradle` file.

In your case, in each root folder of your project you have to define some files, like `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` in which you define the single modules used by the project.

Somenthing like this:

```
github repo
 root
 |---module
 |------build.gradle
 |settings.gradle
 |build.gradle

 root1
 |---module
 |------build.gradle
 |settings.gradle
 |build.gradle
```

Comment: Thanks the problem is that the root of the project is regular repo no assigned with android or gradle so I don't have gradle for it

Comment: But can you add the settings.gradle and build.gradle inside the folders?

Comment: I can but the point is: the project is based on eclipse. I make this to migrate him to Android Studio as new branch...

Comment: and for specific module ain't gradle settings is per project and the project is simple repo in the rule of container

Comment: @michael check the updated answer. Eclipse and Android Studio have different workspaces. If you want to migrate the entire workspace in single projects with modules, you have to specify the gradle file as described in the answer.